# MySql PHP Combine Select Queries

Tags: php, mysql

3 types of information I need from database I know how to get all products ids available in the database but I also want to get the price and the attribute for each productid and have it in a php loop to be able to insert it to other table all information combined

I just want to combine all this 3 infromation and insert into custom table how can I combine it or should I loop to get price + attribute for each product ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't it be as simple as -

```
SELECT `cpet`.`Product_ID`, `cpet`.`Product Price`, `cpet`.`Product Attribute` 
FROM `catalog_product_entity_text` AS `cpet`
JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `cpe`
ON `cpet`.`Product_ID` = `cpe`.`entity_id`
WHERE `cept`.`attribute_id` = '139'
```

Comment: at first need to get product_id from `catalog_product_entity` it's different table and only then get by that ID from table `catalog_product_entity_text` also I would like in the end to insert it to other table

Comment: Can you provide your table definitions? You may only need a JOIN query.

Comment: @It's magento tables if this helps? Here is a way to view the structure `http://www.magereverse.com/index/magento-database-diagram/version/1-7-0-2`